# Laravel/PHP logging to console/terminal without concerning about types etc

Tags: php, laravel

Is there sth. similar like console.log() from javascript in php?

The problem which i have in laravel for e.x.

```
error_log($request);
```

is not working, cause $request is not a string etc.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging#introduction

For me this seems too complicated for what i want to archive, honsetly i don't understand it at all.
What is the easiest way to log in laravel/php without thinking about types etc.

Is there maybe a library which i can install and log to terminal without a second though and tedious setup work? maybe a VSCode extension?

Comment: What's so complicated about `Log::error($request)`? With the default configuration in Laravel that will log the `$request` object to `storage/logs/laravel.log`...

Comment: At the end of the day you need to write a string to a log somewhere and not all objects so broadly speaking `error_log(strval($request));` should work but not all objects get converted to strings in a meaningful way. Some objects do, for others it makes more sense to use `json_encode(..)` to convert them to JSON strings. There is no simple way to get meaningful logs when dealing with objects.

Comment: What's so complicated about Log::error($request)? Nothing, but i'll have to open the file, use the mouse wheel to get to the end, and the horizontal bar, get tons of overhead... compared the javascript logging seems quite complicated in php. I also tried this approach, https://osi.codes/how-to-consolelog-in-laravel, but i doesn't seems to work.

Comment: error_log(strval($request)); doesn't show anything but in laravel.log, local.ERROR: Object of class PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCreateRequest could not be converted  to string {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0)... this helps at least in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a pretty solution but since you want something similar to console.logs in javascript, you can change the log channel in your `.env` file to point to `stderr` which will basically send your logs to your console. That would be if you were already running the application with `php artisan serve`. The logs would appear in the console or terminal where you are running the serve application command.

Change this line in .env
`LOG_CHANNEL=stack to LOG_CHANNEL=stderr`

It might not be pretty because all logs would appear on the console but I think that might be what you are looking for.